# CustomEditor: Показать/скрыть переменные класса в инспекторе по значению перечисления Enum

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я могу сделать ScriptableObject с перечислением и динамическим изменением показываемой переменной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при изменении значения MyType в инспекторе, нужная переменная высвечивается, остальные скрываются.
Сделано это такими простыми скриптами:

**ScriptableObject класс:**

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New File", menuName = "New SOClass", order = 51)]
public class SOClass : ScriptableObject
{
    public enum Type { A, B, C }

    public Type MyType;
    public int IntForA;
    public string StringForB;
    public Vector3 BoundsForC;
}
```

**Editor:**

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SOClass))]
public class SOClassEditor : Editor
{
    private SOClass Target;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Target = (SOClass)target;
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        Target.MyType = (SOClass.Type) EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("MyType", Target.MyType);
        switch (Target.MyType)
        {
            case SOClass.Type.A:
                Target.IntForA = EditorGUILayout.IntField("IntForA", Target.IntForA); break;
            case SOClass.Type.B:
                Target.StringForB = EditorGUILayout.TextField("StringForB", Target.StringForB); break;
            case SOClass.Type.C:
                Target.VectorForC = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("BoundsForC", Target.BoundsForC); break;
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

---

Можно ли сделать что-то подобное для ScriptableObject с ***массивом*** типа такого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура класса такая:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New file", menuName = "New Complex Class", order = 52)]
public class SOClass2 : ScriptableObject
{
    public InnerClass[] Array;
    // Другие переменные...
}

[System.Serializable]
public class InnerClass
{
    public enum Type { A, B, C }

    public Type MyType;
    public int IntForA;
    public string StringForB;
    public Vector3 VectorForC;
}
```

---

Я хотел просто скрыть ненужные переменные. Я использовал [`SerializedObject.FindProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.FindProperty.html), [`SerializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex.html), чтобы ПОЛУЧИТЬ эти Property, но так и не понял, как их **СКРЫТЬ**?  Или же я вынужден ПОЛНОСТЬЮ отрисовывать свой инспектор, т.е. для всех переменных, и иного выхода нет?

> В принципе, именно ScriptableObject здесь не важен. Вопрос о CustomEditor в целом

Comment: Важный оффтоп: данный код легко сломается, если количество контролов в ветках switch'а будет разным.

Answer (score 2):

Писать `Editor` всегда тот еще геморой, нужно отрисовывать весь инспектор, что не так трудно пока поля базовых типов или базовых структур юнити но легко превращается в ужас. `Editor` это только отрисовка компонента/SO в инспекторе, массив так не отрисовать.

Для отрисовки сериализуемых сущьностей (классы и структуры) как поля в инспекторе чего-либо используется [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html). `Vector3` x, y, z отрисовывается так, иначе он был бы в 3 строчки, а не одну. То-же самое касается и других структур юнити, как к примеру `Color` r, g, b, a, где вместо полей вообще rect с цветом призывабщий окно выбора цвета.

Но лично я советовал бы не тратить на это время если это возможно. Это инструмент экономии времени и создании понятного и удобного инструмента для дизайнеров, которые будет этим МНОГО пользоватсья, а не для красоты.